# second monitor is mirrored and can't be changed

Tags: graphics, multiple-monitors, display, amd-graphics, amdgpu-pro

I have dual monitors on my desktop. Recently my second monitor is now mirroring my first monitor, my multiple work spaces have been deleted, and the resolution has dropped substantially.

Graphics    Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 4.0, 128 bits)

I have recently installed AMDGPU-PRO.

I would appriciate any help.

Comment: I would think that `AMDGPU-PRO` is the cause of your problems!

Comment: originally I had downloaded AMDGPU-PRO because I was receiving some errors when launching steam but I have now removed AMDGPU-PRO and all problems are fixed. I guess I sould have done that first.